# Xamarin, Android: Change name of whole app, not just the Label

Tags: android, xamarin

this might sound like a simple question, but I haven't been able to find a solution to this:

I created an app that I now want to publish, but while debugging, this app had an incorrect name.

Now, ofcourse I can change the namespace and / or label in my MainActivity, so that the app on my phone gets the right name assigned to - but if you check this app under "application" it still has its original name.

Is there anyway how I can change all of my Apps name in like "one click"? I did find a few instances, in which the "old" name still appeared, but changing one led to this app no longer debugging.

I'm using Visual Studio :)

THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change it in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Nice ! If it was a solution you can check my answer to help others if they have the same issue :)

Comment: yeah i did, i wanted to do it earlier, but the webpage didnt let me before at least 10 min had passed xD

Comment: Ahahaha xD 
Good coding :D